# windows geth "path not updated" problem during installation

Tags: go-ethereum

When I try to install geth to my Windows 10 pc, I have faced two problem.

first, Although my computer has intel cpu, geth Windows executable is for amd architecture. I could not find any executable for intel. The name of the exectable is: geth-windows-amd64-1.6.7-ab5646c5.exe

Second, I have tried to install geth with the previous executable, but it shows below given warning. Afterward, altough it seems installation completed successfully. geth command could not be found when I type on cmd. You can find related screenshots below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do not worry amd64 executables should run without problems in intel processors. The more neutral name is x86_64, but intel calls it em64t and amd amd64, they are all the same from a user perspective.

Comment: i have also added my path variable in environmental variables and tried to execute geth command on my cmd but it still isn't working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try and go directly to your geth path and execute it from there. Looks like it's in C:\Program Files\Geth

Comment: Yes, you are right :) I have add "C:\Program Files\Geth" to Path in environment variables. And restart command prompts. it works.  thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to add the Geth path to the environment variables.

You can do this by going to Control Panel>System>Advanced System Settings>Environment Variables>Path and add the path of Geth (C:\Program Files\Geth).

Restart the Command Prompt and it should work.